# Uncaught TypeError: isOpen is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was trying to convert my class-based component to function based component, which I wrote some while when I was learning REACT, while converting this, I got an error that isOpen is not the function which I kinda dint get as I defined it as a state and called in handleToggle(), which is then being called at the logo of my component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "../images/logo.svg";
import { FaAlignRight } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

export default function Navbar(){

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
   
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(null);
  
 useEffect(() =>{
  handleToggle();
 });
  
  // state = {
  //   isOpen: false,
  // };
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(isOpen() );
  };



    return (
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="nav-center">
          <div className="nav-header">
            <Link to="/">
              <img src={logo} alt="Beach Resort" />
            </Link>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="nav-btn"
              onClick={handleToggle}
            >
              <FaAlignRight className="nav-icon" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul
            className={isOpen ? "nav-links show-nav" : "nav-links"}
          >
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/rooms">Rooms</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <Badge badgeContent={4} color="primary" 
              id="basic-button"
              aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
              onClick={handleClick}
          >
            <i className="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping text-light"
              style={{ fontSize: 25, cursor: "pointer" }}
            ></i>
          </Badge>
        </div>
        <Menu
        id="basic-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      </nav>
    );
  }
```

EVERY PIECE OF ADVICE WILL BE APPRECIATED

Comment: Because it's not. Why do you try to call it? Should be `setIsOpen(!isOpen)` probably

Answer (score 1):

`isOpen` is a value, not a function. Try `setIsOpen(p => !p)`

Answer (score 1):

`useState` returns an array with two things: a value that is stored in state, and a function to update it. If you call `const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(null)`, `isOpen` is your value (originally set as `null`) and `setIsOpen` is a function to update it.

When you write `const handleToggle = () => { setIsOpen(isOpen() ) }`, you're trying to call a `null` value, which is impossible because it's not a function. That's what the error message is telling you.

Given you want to toggle the value for `isOpen`, what you should do instead is declare `isOpen` as a boolean, and call `setIsOpen` with the opposite of `isOpen`:

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);  // <= set this originally to false

const handleToggle = () => {
  setIsOpen(!isOpen); // <= this will set isOpen as true when it is false, and false when it is true
};
```

However, if you call `handleToggle` inside a `useEffect` with no dependency array, like you're doing, it will be called every time there is a rerender, which is probably not what you want. You most likely want to call this in response to a user interaction - so in response to an HTML element event (like `onClick`). Otherwise you should refactor your code to add the necessary dependencies to `useEffect`.